# Repeating code to add blank rows in dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to replicate the following code 4 times:

> df3_1<- df3_1 %>% add_row(.before
> = 2)

I tried the 'rep' function but it didn't work out. Is there any way to repeat this code 4 times so I can add multiple blank rows exactly in the manner described above (i.e. with respect to a specific row number).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please include a sample of df3_1? Use `dput(df3_1)` to post the data in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can do:

```
n <- 4

nr <- nrow(df3_1)
df3_1[append(seq(nr), values = rep(nr + 1, n), after = 1), ]
```

Or a tidyverse approach:

```
library(tibble) 

n <- 4

df3_1 %>% 
  add_row(!!names(.)[1] := rep(NA, n), .before = 2)
```

Comment: I tried running your tidyverse answer to better understand what the code was doing; using the data frame above generated this error: `Error in eval_tidy(xs[[j]], mask) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'`. I'm using tibble v 3.0.1

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is unless you provide the code used and a sample of data that reproduces the error.

Comment: Data frame and code used: `df3_1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])`
`df3_1 %>%   tibble::add_row(!!names(.)[1] := rep(NA, n), .before = 2)`

Comment: Make sure `n` has been defined (although not defining it led to a slightly different error than the one you encountered) -  `library(tibble); n <- 3; df3_1 %>% tibble::add_row(!!names(.)[1] := rep(NA, n), .before = 2)`.

Comment: Opps,  silly me the n is defined in the base r approach, sorry not to have spotted this. Thanks for pointing this out. Works perfectly now.

Comment: I understand that `!!names(.)[1]` captures the name of the first variable  could you explain how or why `:=`  is required to make the function work?

Comment: Using tidyeval `:=` is necessary if argument names are being unquoted (i.e. operating on the left hand side).

Answer (score 1):

Try this (updated simplified version based on @27ϕ9 generalised approach):

```r
df3_1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
                    b = letters[1:5])

library(dplyr)


  df3_1 %>%
  add_row(a = rep(NA, 4), .before = 2)

#>    a    b
#> 1  1    a
#> 2 NA <NA>
#> 3 NA <NA>
#> 4 NA <NA>
#> 5 NA <NA>
#> 6  2    b
#> 7  3    c
#> 8  4    d
#> 9  5    e
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would think `base::Reduce()` or `purrr::reduce()` are best designed for this kind of job

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df3_1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
                    b = letters[1:5])

# purrr reduce
reduce(1:4,
       function(df, x){
         add_row(df, .before = 2)
       },
       .init = df3_1)
#>    a    b
#> 1  1    a
#> 2 NA <NA>
#> 3 NA <NA>
#> 4 NA <NA>
#> 5 NA <NA>
#> 6  2    b
#> 7  3    c
#> 8  4    d
#> 9  5    e

# base R Reduce
Reduce(function(df, x){
         add_row(df, .before = 2)
       },
       1:4,
       init = df3_1)
#>    a    b
#> 1  1    a
#> 2 NA <NA>
#> 3 NA <NA>
#> 4 NA <NA>
#> 5 NA <NA>
#> 6  2    b
#> 7  3    c
#> 8  4    d
#> 9  5    e
```

You dont actually need the x parameter here inside of your function but to determine how often the function should be called, that is, how many blank rows should be inserted.